# Start array search on the END of the (2D) array

Tags: c#, arrays

I'd like to start the search of an `int` in my array on the end of the array, not at the beginning. How do I do this?

Please keep in mind that it's a 2D array.

*edit* someone asked how I search from the start:

In my code file I'm printing a matrix from 8x8 displaying random numbers (1 - 10). The user gives a number to search in the matrix, and the code gives back the position in which the number is FIRST found:

```
Position position = new Position();

    Position LookForNumber(int[,] matrix, int findNumber)
    {
        for (int r = 0; r < matrix.GetLength(0); r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < matrix.GetLength(1); c++)
            {
                if (matrix[r, c] == findNumber)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your number {0} first appears on position {1},{2}", findNumber, r, c);
                    position.row = r;
                    position.column = c;
                    return position;
                }
            }
        }
        return position;
    }
```

Now I'd like to find the last position of the number that the user gave up.

Comment: Provide example how you perform search from begin, and we will fix it to search from end. We even explain it.

Comment: `for(int i = array.length; i>0; i--)` is this what you looking for?

Comment: @eocron I edited my post.

Comment: I edited my answer, based on your edit on question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To Search a 2D array you would need 2 loops, however you may do the loops in revearse order:

```
    Position LookForNumber(int[,] matrix, int findNumber)
    {
        Position position = new Position();
        for (int r = matrix.GetLength(0) - 1; r >= 0 ; r--)
        {
            for (int c = matrix.GetLength(1) - 1; c >= 0 ; c--)
            {
                if (matrix[r, c] == findNumber)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your number {0} first appears on position 
              {1},{2}", findNumber, r, c);
                    position.row = r;
                    position.column = c;
                    return position;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I hate it when the copy-paste answer wins :(

Comment: @GilSand I had actually written a totally different answer, and edited and used OP's code after he edited his question, to best match his question, you may checked the edits to answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

The fact the array is 2D is irrelevant to your issue.

See how the most regular basic loops works?

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length ; i++)
{
...
}
```

You're essentially doing this, if you had to translate code to english

**For all elements, starting with** `0` **that we're assigning to** `i`**, stopping before we reach** `array.length`**, and** `adding 1 to i between each iteration`**, do the following** `(...)`

So all you have to do really, is change the parameters of the loop.

For example, you could say your starting point (which is `i`), could be something other than 0. What would you use instead of zero if you want to start at the end of your array?

Then, if you're starting at the end, can you really ADD values to `i` between each iterations ? Not really, you'd go out of bounds, so what should you do instead of `i++` ?

At that point, you need a stopping point if you're iterating from end to start. And the answer lies in the question : my stopping point is the start of the array. So the middle parameter of your loop (which is the stopping point) should be something that represents the start of your array. How would you write that down?

Note that you could also iterate every second element now that you understand the logic, for example.

And the fact you're in a 2D loop just means you need one inner loop inside your main loop, which will work the same way as the outer loop. Just imagine the indexes as a canvas with coordinates, instead of just a line with points.

If you don't understand all I meant I'll just write down the answer, but I think the explanation is clear enough that you will understand :)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, really usefull.